# can i make several scripts work on a request in Fiddler?

Tags: request, fiddler

[image: example demo]

Suppose there is a url, "http://test.com/cgi-bin/static/index.html",I want both scripts work.Is it possible to pass through the request on several fiddler scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [Fiddler Book](https://fiddlerbook.com):

> *script-specified functions whose names contain the word **filter** cause the
>   rule to be treated as non-Final, allowing subsequent rules to apply.

So if you wanted your `saveLogin` function not to prevent the `host81` rule from being evaluated, rename `saveLogin` to something like `saveLogin_filter`.